# Only have "replay" at the end of YouTube video

Tags: youtube

I've managed to remove the suggested related videos from the end of a YouTube video by using `&rel=0`.

However, I still have the permalink, and the HTML embedding code at the end. How can remove those?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modifying YouTube "end of video" page](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19619/modifying-youtube-end-of-video-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're talking about when embedding the video in your own site:

You can use the [Chromeless player](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/chromeless_player_reference.html) to accomplish this. You will have to set up your own play/pause, etc. controls, as well as your own replay button, but that's the trade-off for having full control.

See: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/chromeless_example_1.html for an example.