# Modifying YouTube "end of video" page

Tags: youtube

I would like to have an introductory video on my homepage, and I'm considering embedding a YouTube player.

A problem I see is that, at the end of the video, YouTube will be suggesting other videos. This is a good chance for users to "escape" the website.

Can I somehow modify this "end of video" page so that it displays a blank screen, or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  There's a `rel=0` parameter for precisely this purpose, that was introduced in June 2007.  Read the [YouTube embedded player parameter documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks. That removes the related videos. However, how can I remove the "permalink" and "embedding HTML"? I just want a "Replay" button.